# Deploy React App to Netlify with Server file in root directory

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, create-react-app, netlify

I a created a custom server.js file to get around React's inability to generate dynamic metadata for open graph procotol) for pages other than index.html.

I'm using Create React App and [followed this tutorial](https://blog.logrocket.com/adding-dynamic-meta-tags-react-app-without-ssr/) to handle the meta tags replacement on the server side before the pages get generated. Locally, it all works and when I serve the node.js file I can see that the pages change meta tags correctly.

The problem occurs when deploying the app to Netlify, I'm not sure what I need to specify to make sure the server.js file is executed before loading the application (or executed at all). I'm pasting a screenshot of the directory below.

Anyone knows of any trick to make sure Netlify runs this file together with the app?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LFBZ5.png)

Tried using serverless functions from Netlify but that does not support express.js